# Windows Minifilter Driver: Error Faced - fltmc load failed with error: 0x8007007f the specified procedure could not be found

Tags: windows-kernel, minifilter, windows-driver

This post is for any driver developer facing the same issue and looking for some solution.

I Faced this error while loading the minifilter driver.
The minifilter driver build was successful.
The minifilter driver installation on Target machine was successful.
But when I tried to load the driver: `fltmc load xxx`. This returned an error: **"fltmc load failed with error: 0x8007007f the specified procedure could not be found."**

The result was same when I tried to start the service. `net start xxx`.

On querying the status of the service: `sc query xxx`, it displayed an error of **win32_exit_code : 127 (0x7f)**

This had me stumped.

I tried dependency walker to check the APIs that are missing. This gave a lot of details and whole 2 days to debugging and figuring out the issue.

I finally figured out that the problem lied in the WDK i was using to build the driver. So, in my case I used WDK version 10.0.22000.1. The driver build with this WDK was giving this error.
When I downgraded and used WDK version 10.0.19041, I was able to use the driver without any issue.
There were some APIs that were downgraded in the upgraded WDK.

Thus, if facing the issue try with upgrading or downgrading the WDK and check the difference between the two. It might help.